# Confusion in understanding portlet terms

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal

Can you please explain in lay terms to a beginner:
What is the difference between : A portlet, A portlet label, A potlet page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [WebSphere Portal Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/genservers/portal/server/).

- [Portlets](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/dev/wpsbpc.html)
- [Pages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/h_mp_create_pages.html)
- [Labels](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/mp_create_labels.html)
- [Managing Pages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/mp_manage_pages.html)